# Dividing convex hull into multiple hulls in matlab

Tags: matlab, convex-hull

I am facing a problem on how to break down a convex hull into multiple hulls. I know how to merge convex hulls but is there any way to divide them, although them being a being of a same category. 
Is there any algorithm where a convex hull is divided with the same boundary being shared with other hulls? 
I want to implement this in Matlab.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the code you already worked on? See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How to ask) for more info.

Comment: A convex hull is a convex polygon. You can of course divide a polygon up into smaller ones. Please clarify your question. How do you want to divide the polygon? What do you mean with "same boundary"?

Comment: Same boundary in the sense, let's say I have got two convex hulls(A,B) for my data points and I want to merge both of them, one way is two merge them directly but there will lot of useless space in between, another way is to break one hull into 2 hulls(A1,A2) and then merge A2 with B. Here convex hulls A1 and A2 will share a common boundary between them.

Comment: If not this then is there any way to create a parallel edge inside the hull ? This will solve the problem.